# Windows error 2203 when installing TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows-7, installation, tortoise-svn

I keep getting this error when trying to install TortoiseSVN on Windows 7.

> All Windows-help documents refer to Windows XP for this error code and
>   they don't work with Windows 7.

What does this message mean?

Note: My version number is TortoiseSVN-1.6.7.18415-win32-svn-1.6.9

EDIT: I just tried installing the latest stable version of TortoiseGit ([Link, 32-bit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/downloads/list)), and I get the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your temp directory doesn't have full access set for the SYSTEM user.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem until I realized I was using the 32 bit installer on a 64 bit windows server box. Opps. I completely uninstalled the old version and then installed the 64 bit version of TortoiseSVN, restarted and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem when I used SUBST on the drive on which I was storing my temp directory. Seems windows (XP) can't understand permissions when SUBST is used.